# Запушить json в firebase c emberjs

Tags: javascript, база-данных, ember.js, firebase

Всем привет. 
Не могу понять, как запушить json в определенный объект. Делаю блог с категориями, где в категориях есть поле hasMany().

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу именно попасть в коллекцию. Вот мой примерный код добавления.

```
var catId = this.get('category');
var postId = newPost.id;
newPost.save();

var addtocat = this.store.push('category', catId.posts, {
    postId : true
});
addtocat.save();
```

Сам пост добавляю, потом беру у создавшегося поста id и вставляю в категорию.

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
Метод push класса store использовать не надо. Его очень редко используют. Его используют когда, например, пишут адаптер/сериализатор.
И вообще, если не ошибаюсь, метод push принимает аргумент в виде объекта в формате json-api.
У вас должно быть примерно следующее:

```
// app/models/post.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  autor: DS.attr("string"),
  body: DS.attr("string"),
  publish: DS.attr("date"),
  title: DS.attr("string"),
  category: DS.belongsTo("category")
});

// app/models/category.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr("string"),
  path: DS.attr("string"),
  posts: DS.hasMany("post")
})
```

И в каком-нибудь месте (route) вы пишите т.е. начинаете работать

```
// создаете post например так
let post = this.store.createRecord('post', {
   autor: "Vasya",
   body: "Body",
   publish: new Date(),
   title: "Title",
});
// допустим сохраним на сервере
post.save();

// затем создадим category
let category = this.store.createRecord('category', {
   name: "Технологии",
   path: "Tech"
});
category.get("posts").pushObject(post);
category.save();
```

Как-то так. Где-то мог конечно и ошибиться.

Ссылки:
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/models/relationships/
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#stq=&stp=0